# .getDefaultCloseOperation getting strange error

Tags: java

When I call getDefaultCloseOperation it gives me this error
https://gyazo.com/fac35aa3baf4eb07f8d241da8a782945

Here is the (relevant part of the) Server class:
https://gyazo.com/38dfbefbbaabba832ca6121f5e6b1001

Comment: Are they links to `virus on my computer` ?

Comment: Perhaps you mean to `.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` ?

Comment: The argument I'm passing in it should be fine, as seen on this video: https://youtu.be/MYjodmqION0?t=1m26s

Answer (score 0):

Method `public int getDefaultCloseOperation()` from `JFrame` class doesn't accept any arguments. So, remove `int` argument

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
JFrame server1 = new Server();
```

Comment: Now I'm getting a type mismatch: Cannot convert from server to JFrame

Comment: Ya that's wrong anyways. I just tested what you have in your code and it works for me

Comment: Just figured it out--They were in separate pacakages! =\ Thanks for the help.